# has anyone installed ubuntu on M.2 PCIe NVME Gen 4x4 Class 40 2280 Solid State Drive - 2TB internal hard drive

Tags: 20.04, ssd

has anyone installed ubuntu 20.04 on M.2 PCIe NVME Gen 4x4 Class 40 2280 Solid State Drive - 2TB internal hard drive

Comment: This question is off-topic as asked.  You should only ask practical answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.  If you are experiencing a particular problem, you should search/research about that problem and if you still need help, give details about the problem, catch us up on your research and attempts to fix the issue on your own. If you are asking for hardware recommendations, they are off topic since hardware recommendations are opinion based.

Comment: I run Ubuntu from a samsung evo plus 970, a 500 GB drive in the 2280 form factor.  I also have a 2 TB ssd, which is my data drive.